# Samsung S9(18:9) camera preview stretched

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-camera

I am using Android Camera API and it works good 16:9 ratio devices on both portrait and landscape modes. But in Samsung S9 18:9 ratio device, on landscape mode the preview looks stretched. On Samsung S9 I got following supported preview sizes, `1920X1080,1440X1080, 1088X1088,1280X720,1056X704, 1024X768, 960X720,800X450,720X720,720X480,640X480,352X288,320X240,256X144,176X144` So optimal preview size is `1920X1080` but actual resolution of device is `2,220 x 1,080`. So that it looks stretched.But I need preview on full screen.How default camera preview shows on fullscreen?

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera.PreviewCallback previewCallback) {
        super(context);
        this.previewCallback = previewCallback;
        mContext = context;
        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Context activity,
                                            int cameraId, Camera camera) {
        Camera.CameraInfo info =
                new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
        int rotation = ((AppCompatActivity) activity).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                .getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degrees = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degrees = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degrees = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degrees = 270;
                break;
        }

        int result;
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
        } else {  // back-facing
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }


        mDisplayOrientation = result;

        Log.d(TAG, "setCameraDisplayOrientation: "+mDisplayOrientation);

        camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);

    }



    public void takePhoto(final PictureCallback pCalback) {
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, pCalback);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
        // to draw.
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
            //previewCount = 0;
        }

        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open();


            //setCameraDisplayOrientation(mContext, 0, mCamera);
            /*mParameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
            int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
            optimalPreviewSize = getBestAspectPreviewSize(mParameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes(), screenWidth, screenHeight);//Bug Fix for Samsung A8
            mParameters.setPreviewSize(optimalPreviewSize.width, optimalPreviewSize.height);
            mParameters.setPictureSize(optimalPreviewSize.width, optimalPreviewSize.height);
            mParameters.setPreviewFpsRange(30000, 30000);
            mCamera.setParameters(mParameters);*/
            /*mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(previewCallback);*/


            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
            //previewCount = 0;
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            mCamera = null;
            //previewCount = 0;
        }

        if (mCameraPreviewListener != null) {
            mCameraPreviewListener.onCameraSurfaceCreated();
        }
    }



    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
            //previewCount = 0;
        }
        if (mCameraPreviewListener != null) {
            mCameraPreviewListener.onCameraSurfaceDestroyed();
        }
    }

    public void stopCamera() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
            //previewCount = 0;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        try {
            // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
            // the preview.
            mParameters = mCamera.getParameters();

            Log.d("CameraFix", "parameters -> " + mParameters.flatten());

            setCameraDisplayOrientation(mContext, 0, mCamera);


            mParameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);

            //Size optimalPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mParameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes(), getWidth(), getHeight());
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
            int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

            //Size optimalPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mParameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes(), screenWidth, screenHeight, getHeight());
            mSupportedPreviewSizes = mParameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            optimalPreviewSize = getBestAspectPreviewSize(mParameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes(), screenWidth, screenHeight);//Bug Fix for Samsung A8

            Log.d("CameraFix", "optimalPreviewSize.width -> " + optimalPreviewSize.width);
            Log.d("CameraFix", "optimalPreviewSize.height -> " + optimalPreviewSize.height);

            mParameters.setPreviewSize(optimalPreviewSize.width, optimalPreviewSize.height);
            mParameters.setPictureSize(optimalPreviewSize.width, optimalPreviewSize.height);
            mParameters.setPreviewFpsRange(30000, 30000);

            /*if (mDisplayOrientation == 0 || mDisplayOrientation == 180) {
                setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(optimalPreviewSize.width, optimalPreviewSize.height,Gravity.CENTER));
            }*/


            Log.d("CameraFix", "setPreviewFpsRange");

            mCamera.setParameters(mParameters);

            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

            //SurfaceTexture st = new SurfaceTexture(10);
            //mCamera.setPreviewTexture(st);
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(previewCallback);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            Log.d("CameraFix", "start preview");
            if (mCameraPreviewListener != null) {
                mCameraPreviewListener.onCameraSurfaceChanged();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("CameraFix", e.toString());
        }

    }

public void toggleFlash(boolean flashModeOn) {
        if (mContext.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
            Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            if (flashModeOn) {
                //parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
                mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                //Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.flash_mode_on, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
                //Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.flash_mode_off, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.flash_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

/**
     * Source for this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21354313/camera-preview-quality-in-android-is-poor/21354442#21354442
     *
     * @param supportedPreviewSizes
     * @param screenWidth
     * @param screenHeight
     * @return
     */
    private Size getBestAspectPreviewSize(List<Size> supportedPreviewSizes, int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {
        double targetRatio = (double) screenWidth / screenHeight;
        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        for (int i = 0; i < supportedPreviewSizes.size(); i++) {
            Size size = supportedPreviewSizes.get(i);
            Log.d(TAG, "getBestAspectPreviewSize: supportedPreviewSizes -> "+size.width +"X"+size.height);
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "getBestAspectPreviewSize: supportedPreviewSizes -> "+supportedPreviewSizes.toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "getBestAspectPreviewSize: mDisplayOrientation -> "+mDisplayOrientation);

        if (mDisplayOrientation == 90 || mDisplayOrientation == 270) {
            Log.d(TAG, "getBestAspectPreviewSize: inside 90 - 270 ");
            targetRatio = (double) screenHeight / screenWidth;
        }


        Log.d(TAG, "getBestAspectPreviewSize: targetRatio -> "+targetRatio);

        Collections.sort(supportedPreviewSizes,
                Collections.reverseOrder(new SizeComparator()));

        for (Size size : supportedPreviewSizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;

            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio);
            }

            if (minDiff < 0.0d) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return (optimalSize);

        /*if (mDisplayOrientation == 0 || mDisplayOrientation == 180) {
            if (optimalSize != null) {
                return mCamera.new Size(optimalSize.height, optimalSize.width);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        else{
            return (optimalSize);
        }*/

        //return mCamera.new Size(2220,1080);
    }

    public int getDisplayOrientation() {
        return mDisplayOrientation;
    }

    public void setDisplayOrientation(int displayOrientation) {
        this.mDisplayOrientation = displayOrientation;
    }

    public Parameters getCameraParameters() {
        return mCamera.getParameters();
    }

public void setCameraPreviewListener(CameraPreviewListener cameraPreviewListener) {
        mCameraPreviewListener = cameraPreviewListener;
    }

    public interface CameraPreviewListener {
        void onCameraSurfaceCreated();

        void onCameraSurfaceChanged();

        void onCameraSurfaceDestroyed();

        void onCameraPreviewStarted();
    }

    private static class SizeComparator implements
            Comparator<Size> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
            int left = lhs.width * lhs.height;
            int right = rhs.width * rhs.height;

            if (left < right) {
                return (-1);
            } else if (left > right) {
                return (1);
            }

            return (0);
        }
    }
```

[image: S9 Camera stretched in landscape mode]

Comment: From your picture we see that this is not totally full screen. You have the nav bar on the right  and the system toolbar on top. Why not to add a bit of black margins to keep the preview window aspect ratio 16:9?

Comment: camera preview is fullscreen and added the navbar on top that in Framelayout...I understand there is no way without canter the preview and add some spaces. So set preview size as 1920X1080 and centered the preview.Now it looks like frame for preview. But still dont understand why not samsung provides the supported preview size even they already know it.

Comment: I wholeheartely support your rhetorical question. Note that you still have an alternative option, to fill all width of the screen but crop the preview frame on top and bottom (that's like adding margins of negative size).

Comment: @Ramprasad Hi Ram Can you please take a look into my code which is posted an answer and let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should check the displayable area of default camera again. I don't think it can display fully without stretch in that resolution. It may have a black area, toolbar, status bar...
2. There is nothing wrong in your implementation. We have to find the best support preview size compare with surface view which you want to display. In this case, you should make the surface view (1920 x 1080) in center, then add black padding areas on top and bottom.

Comment: I set preview size as 1920X1080 and centered the preview.Now it looks like frame for preview. But still dont understand why not samsung provides fullscreen size as supported preview size even they already know it.

Comment: We have no idea about providers. When developed a photo sharing application, I faced this issue in many devices. In some devices, you can choose the preview resolution, they will crop the preview to keep the ratio. You have to choose the best way to handle all of them. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Please take look into my answer hope it will help, I resolved the stretch issue by the following code, method name might change. I share my implementation, Because I know how hard to implement camera in Android, So please don't hesitate to see the following section.

**Invoke loadCamera method in ButtonAction.**

```
private void loadCamera() {
        if (CommonUtils.deviceHasCamera(getActivityContext)) {
            startBackgroundThread();
            mCameraTimeOut=(isPermissionGranted?2500:5000);
            if (mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
                openCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
            } else {
                mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
            }
        }else{
            ShowToastUtils.INSTANCE.showCustomToast(getActivityContext, getString(R.string.msg_no_camera));
        }
    }
```

**Initially SurfaceListener Invoked for Camera**

```
private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener
            = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture,
                                              int width, int height) {
            mCameraTimeOut=(isPermissionGranted?2500:5000);
            Log.e(TAG1, "chooseOptimalSize"+"-SurfaceTextureListener ---=>Width---=>"+width);
            Log.e(TAG1, "chooseOptimalSize"+"-SurfaceTextureListener ---=>Height---=>"+height);
            openCamera(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture,
                                                int width, int height) {
            configureTransform(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {}

    };
```

**To Choose Optimal Preview Size for Texture**

```
//Samsung-S6-choices[0]
//Samsung-S7-edge-choices[6]
//OnePlus-5T-choices[15]
/*Following is used for Camera Preview in TextureView,  based on device camera resolution*/
    /*
     * Given {@code choices} of {@code Size}s supported by a camera, chooses the smallest one whose
     * width and height are at least as large as the respective requested values, and whose aspect
     * ratio matches with the specified value.
     *
     * @param choices     The list of sizes that the camera supports for the intended output class
     * @param width       The minimum desired width
     * @param height      The minimum desired height
     * @param aspectRatio The aspect ratio
     * @return The optimal {@code Size}, or an arbitrary one if none were big enough
     */

     private  Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int width, int height, Size aspectRatio) {
        // Collect the supported resolutions that are at least as big as the preview Surface

        int loopCounter=0;
        Log.e(TAG1, "Screen-->Width x Height="+screenWidth+" x "+screenHeight);
        for (Size size : choices) {
            Log.e(TAG1, "chooseOptimalSize:"+size);
        }
        for (Size size : choices) {
            int orientation = getActivityContext.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                if((size.getWidth()/16) == (size.getHeight()/9) && size.getWidth() <=7680 ) {//8K UHDTV Super Hi-Vision
                    Log.e(TAG1, "chooseOptimalSize:"+size.getWidth()+"x"+size.getHeight()+"--LoopPosition---==>"+loopCounter);
                    return size;
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG1, "chooseOptimalSize:--given--"+size);
                if((size.getWidth()/16) == (size.getHeight()/9) && ((size.getWidth() <=1280)||(size.getHeight()<=1920))) {
                    mCameraRatio=RATIO_16_9;
                    Log.e(TAG1, "chooseOptimalSize:"+size.getWidth()+"x"+size.getHeight()+"-16:9"+"--LoopPosition---==>"+loopCounter);
                    return size;
                }else if((size.getWidth()/18) == (size.getHeight()/9) && ((size.getWidth() <=2160)||(size.getHeight()<=3840))) {
                    mCameraRatio=RATIO_18_9;
                    Log.e(TAG1, "chooseOptimalSize:"+size.getWidth()+"x"+size.getHeight()+"-18:9"+"--LoopPosition---==>"+loopCounter);
                    return size;
                }else if((size.getWidth()/18.5) == (size.getHeight()/9) && ((size.getWidth() <=2160)||(size.getHeight()<=3840))) {
                    mCameraRatio=RATIO_18_9;
                    Log.e(TAG1, "chooseOptimalSize:"+size.getWidth()+"x"+size.getHeight()+"-18.5:9"+"--LoopPosition---==>"+loopCounter);
                    return size;
                }else if((width/19) == (height/9) && ((width <=2208)||(height<=3216))) {
                    mCameraRatio=RATIO_19_9;
                    Log.e(TAG1, "chooseOptimalSize:"+size.getWidth()+"x"+size.getHeight()+"-19:9"+"--LoopPosition---==>"+loopCounter);
                    return size;
                }else if((size.getWidth()/19.5) == (size.getHeight()/9) && ((size.getWidth() <=3840)||(size.getHeight()<=2160))) {
                    mCameraRatio=RATIO_19_9;
                    Log.e(TAG1, "chooseOptimalSize:"+size.getWidth()+"x"+size.getHeight()+"-19.5:9"+"--LoopPosition---==>"+loopCounter);
                    return size;
                }else{
                    Log.e(TAG1, "chooseOptimalSize"+" not proper aspect resolution");
                }
            }
                  loopCounter++;
        }
}
```

**To Open Camera**

```
    private void openCamera(int width, int height) {
                CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getActivityContext.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
                try {
                    Log.e(TAG, "tryAcquire");
                    if (!mCameraOpenCloseLock.tryAcquire(mCameraTimeOut, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Time out waiting to lock camera opening.");
                    }
                    String mCameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[cameraId];
                    // Choose the sizes for camera preview and video recording
                    characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraId);
                    StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
                    try {
                        mSensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
                        maximumZoomLevel = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_AVAILABLE_MAX_DIGITAL_ZOOM);
                        if (map == null) {
                            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot get available preview/video sizes");
                        }
                        mVideoSize = chooseVideoSize(map.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class));
    /*This Line will configure the Texture size*/
                        mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class), width, height, mVideoSize);


int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
                    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                        Log.e(TAG1, "Width" + mPreviewSize.getWidth() + "X Height" + mPreviewSize.getHeight());
                        mTextureView.setAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG1, "Width" + mPreviewSize.getHeight() + "X Height" + mPreviewSize.getWidth());
                        mTextureView.setAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
    //S10 preview Size
                        /* mTextureView.setAspectRatio(1080, 2280);*/
                        //mTextureView.setAspectRatio(2208, 2944);
                    }
                    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                        configureTransform(width, height);
                    }

                    if (isPermissionGranted) {
                        manager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, null);
                    }

                }catch (Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}finally {
                    map=null;
                    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
                }
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivityContext, "Cannot access the camera.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //getActivityContext.finish();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera opening.");
            }
        }
```

**ConfigureTransform method used for orientation handling**

```
/*
     * Configures the necessary {@link android.graphics.Matrix} transformation to `mTextureView`.
     * This method should not to be called until the camera preview size is determined in
     * openCamera, or until the size of `mTextureView` is fixed.
     *
     * @param viewWidth  The width of `mTextureView`
     * @param viewHeight The height of `mTextureView`
     */

private void configureTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
    if (null == mTextureView || null == mPreviewSize) {
        return;
    }
    int rotation = getActivityContext.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
    RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
    float centerX = viewRect.centerX();
    float centerY = viewRect.centerY();
    if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {
        bufferRect.offset(centerX - bufferRect.centerX(), centerY - bufferRect.centerY());
        matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
        float scale = Math.max((float) viewHeight / mPreviewSize.getHeight(),(float) viewWidth / mPreviewSize.getWidth());
        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
        matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centerY);
    }else if (Surface.ROTATION_0 == rotation) {
        bufferRect.offset(centerX - bufferRect.centerX(), centerY - bufferRect.centerY());
        matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
        float scale=Math.max((float) viewWidth / mPreviewSize.getWidth(), (float) viewHeight / mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
        matrix.postRotate(0, centerX, centerY);
    }else if(Surface.ROTATION_180== rotation){
        bufferRect.offset(centerX - bufferRect.centerX(), centerY - bufferRect.centerY());
        matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
        float scale=Math.max((float) viewWidth / mPreviewSize.getWidth(), (float) viewHeight / mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
        matrix.postRotate(0, centerX, centerY);
    }
    try {
        mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
    }catch (Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}finally {
        bufferRect=null;
        viewRect=null;
        matrix=null;
    }
}
```

**Finally to Start Preview**

```
private void startPreview() {
        if (null == mCameraDevice || !mTextureView.isAvailable() || null == mPreviewSize) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            closePreviewSession();
            SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            //texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
            mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);
            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Collections.singletonList(previewSurface),
                    new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                            mPreviewSession = session;
                            updatePreview();
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivityContext, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }, mBackgroundHandler);
            //previewSurface=null;
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```